# How can I find records that contain multiple category IDs (using Toxi structure)?

Tags: mysql, tags, taxonomy

**SQL**

```
SELECT *
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN taxonomy_term_map 
ON (posts.ID = taxonomy_term_map.object_id) 
WHERE taxonomy_term_map.term_id 
IN (98,119)
GROUP BY posts.ID DESC
HAVING COUNT(posts.ID ) >= 2
LIMIT 0,20
```

**TABLES & COLUMNS**

posts { ID, post_title, etc... }

taxonomy_terms { term_id, term_label, term_slug, etc. }

post_taxonomy_term_map { map_id, object_id, taxonomy, term_id}
(NOTE: object_id relates to the posts.ID value)

---

My site uses the Toxi taxonomy structure for tagging/categorizing posts. Each post can have multiple term IDs attached to it.

Each taxonomy term associated with a post gets a record in the "post_taxonomy_term_map" table.

The query I'm current using returns matching records at the top of the results ("GROUP BY posts.ID DESC") along with additional records that don't fully match all the terms provided.

I only want to select records that match ALL of the term ID values provided, everything else should be ignored. Additionally, I want to order records by posts.rank, but I can't currently do that while ordering posts by GROUP.

I would appreciate some assistance.

Comment: Your outer join is effectively acting as an inner join since the condition `taxonomy_term_map.term_id IN (98,119)` is not on the `JOIN` clause but on the `WHERE` clause. Fix this first, before we can help you.

Comment: Do you mean something like this...

    SELECT *
    FROM post_taxonomy_term_map m, post_posts p
    WHERE m.term_id IN (98,119)
    AND p.ID = m.object_id
    GROUP BY p.ID DESC
    HAVING COUNT( p.ID ) >=2
    LIMIT 10

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will get what you need:

```
select p.* -- get only the columns from posts
from posts p
join post_taxonomy_term_map m on m.object_id = p.id
where m.term_id in (98, 119) -- filter to specific terms
group by p.id
having count(*) = 2 -- filter out incomplete ones
order by p.rank -- order by rank
limit 20 -- get only the first 20 rows
```